# Functions on header not working - AngularJs & Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to put some functions on the header of my site, but the functions just not working...

I'm building my site with AngularJs and Javascript. Next my `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="adminApp">

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Admin</title>
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link type="text/css" href="app/css/admin.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link type="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.standalone.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<head>

    <base href="/">

</head>
<body>

    <div ng-include="'app/components/include/header.html'"></div>


    <ng-view></ng-view>    


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.22/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.62/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="app/app.js"></script>
<script src="app/components/home/admin-home.js"></script>
<script src="app/components/test/test.js"></script>
<script src="app/components/include/header.js"></script>
<script src="app/factories/admin-factory.js"></script>
<script src="app/routes/admin-route.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, i'm calling the header file on the `ng-include` div.

And the my `header.html` file:

```
<section class="admin-header">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
            <a id="admin-logo"><img src="/logo.png" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 hide" id="login" align="center">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-user" id="jump-btn">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<div class="menu-out">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-logout" id="logout">Log out</button>
</div>
```

So, at this point, everything works fine: the header appears on every page. But if i need a function on the logout button, how can i do it?

I've tried creating a `home.js` file like next one:

```
(function(){

    var head = {
        templateUrl: '/app/components/include/header.html',
        controller: headCtrl
    };

    angular
    .module('adminApp')
    .component('adminHead', head);

    headCtrl.$inject = ["$http", "$scope"];
    function headCtrl($http, $scope){
        $scope.getOut = function(){
            alert('Log out');
        }   
     }

})();
```

And then, added the function on the button with `ng-click`:

```
<div class="menu-out">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-logout" id="logout" ng-click="getOut()">Log out</button>
</div>
```

But the function is not working.

Someone knows why is not working and help me with and example if it's possible, please? If i add the function on the html between script tags works, but i need to find if it's possible with the `$scope`.

Hope you can help me. Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a controller:

```
angular
.module('adminApp')
.controller('adminHeadCtrl', headCtrl);

headCtrl.$inject = ["$http", "$scope"];
function headCtrl($http, $scope){
    $scope.getOut = function(){
        alert('Log out');
    }   
}
```

Instantiate the controller with the `ng-controller` directive:

```html
<div class="menu-out" ng-controller="adminHeadCtrl">
    <button type="button" ng-click="getOut()" id="logout">Log out</button>
</div>
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Controllers](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller)

Comment: Thanks. Now i'm getting the next error: `Argument 'adminHeadCtrl' is not a function, got undefined`. Any idea why is showing that error? I've added the 
`adminHeadCtrl` in the injection and as a function but still the same problem

Comment: I've already resolved: just needed to remove the var `head` and replace with the controller name again. Thanks a lot!